# Adding Stripe javascript disables animations in Bootstrap 3 Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, stripe-payments

I had a fully working carousel, but once I added stripe to my system to enable payments it disabled the animations so it just immediately changes pictures instead of sliding.

The javascript file for my stripe is

```
(function() {
var subscription;

jQuery(function() {
Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
return subscription.setupForm();
});

subscription = {
setupForm: function() {
  return $('#new_subscription').submit(function() {
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
    if ($('#card_number').length) {
      subscription.processCard();
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
},
processCard: function() {
  var card;
  card = {
    name: $('#subscription_name').val(),
    number: $('#card_number').val(),
    cvc: $('#subscription_cvc').val(),
    expMonth: $('#subscription_exp_month').val(),
    expYear: $('#subscription_exp_year').val()
  };
  return Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse);
},
handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
  if (response.error) {
    $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message);
    return $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#subscription_stripe_card_token').val(response.id);
    return $('#new_subscription')[0].submit();
   }
 }
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Please post the code to JSFiddle so we can see it?.

Comment: Well it's hard to put into a JSFiddle since it's a rails project.  I can put everything into the application.  I can get the carousel working, but adding the above JS file doesn't replicate my problem.  Here is the JSFiddle I made:  http://jsfiddle.net/LzdUa/13/

Comment: Yeah., I was thinking that it might be a bit difficult to post. Are you getting any js errors once you add the Stripe script and the carousel breaks?

Comment: No errors that I can find.  Although I think I might have found the issue.  I moved `Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));` outside the jQuery function.  And it seems to have solved the problem with the animations and still works.  I have no idea why this caused it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

When adding stripe to your layout, try removing "application" from the javascript_include_tag.

`<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/", "application" %>`
to
`<%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v1/" %>`

That worked for me.